# save an array in each tabs (QTabWidget) to a 2D array outside of QTabWidget by click on a button outside of QTabWidget

Tags: qt, qtabwidget

in each tab in my QTabWidget, I have an array. For each tab I define a class named "TabView" that contain this array and a QGraphicsScene to draw line on it and some other element. When I open a new tab I do this by my class TabView like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered(){
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"), QDir::currentPath());
    if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {

    tabView = new TabView(fileName);

    ui->tabWidget->addTab(tabView,"someTab");

    QFileInfo fileInfo = fileName;
    ui->tabWidget->setTabText(ui->tabWidget->count()-1,fileInfo.baseName());

    ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(ui->tabWidget->count()-1);
}
```

There is a button **outside of** QTabWidget. I want by click this button store each array on each tab in a 2D array.
but I just access to last opened tab array.

```
tabsArray[index] = tabView->getArray();
```

I need something like this:

```
tabWidget->tab(index)->getArray()
```

Any idea is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is [QTabWidget::currentWidget()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtabwidget.html#currentWidget) what you're looking for? There is also [QTabWidget::widget(int index)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtabwidget.html#widget).

Comment: I can't access to my array in current tab, by tabWidget->currentWidget() **->getMyArray()**
I can't see getMyArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QTabView::currentWidget()` to get your active tab. Cast that to `TabView`, and access the array by using your `getArray()` function. Like this:

```
TabView *active_tab = qobject_cast<TabView*>(ui->tabWidget->currentWidget());
if(active_tab)
    tabsArray[index] = active_tab->getArray();
```